# Excel time not always right converted

Tags: r, excel, datetime, import, posixct

I'm importing Date-time values from [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) and when converting in [datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime) in [r](/questions/tagged/r), some results are good other are wrong. Here are my raw data (from excel):

```
         time excel
1   43033.35662037037
2   43033.35662037037
3   43033.35662037037
4   43033.35662037037
5   43033.35663194444
6   43033.35663194444
7   43033.35663194444
8   43033.35663194444
9   43033.35664351852
10  43033.35664351852
11  43033.35664351852
12  43033.35664351852
13  43033.35665509259
14  43033.35665509259
15  43033.35665509259
16  43033.35665509259
17  43033.35666666667
18  43033.35666666667
19  43033.35666666667
20  43033.35666666667
21  43033.35667824074
```

Here is my code:

```
raw_time$`time excel` = as.numeric(raw_time$`time excel`)
r_time <- data.frame(as.Date(raw_time$`time excel`, origin = "1899-12-30"))
colnames(r_time)<-"time R"
r_time$`time R` <- as.POSIXct(r_time$`time R` , format =  "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS6")
```

And here is what I get:

```
        time excel                   time R

1   43033.35662037037   2017-10-25 10:33:32
2   43033.35662037037   2017-10-25 10:33:32
3   43033.35662037037   2017-10-25 10:33:32
4   43033.35662037037   2017-10-25 10:33:32
5   43033.35663194444   2017-10-25 10:33:33
6   43033.35663194444   2017-10-25 10:33:33
7   43033.35663194444   2017-10-25 10:33:33
8   43033.35663194444   2017-10-25 10:33:33
9   43033.35664351852   2017-10-25 10:33:34
10  43033.35664351852   2017-10-25 10:33:34
11  43033.35664351852   2017-10-25 10:33:34
12  43033.35664351852   2017-10-25 10:33:34
13  43033.35665509259   2017-10-25 10:33:34
14  43033.35665509259   2017-10-25 10:33:34
15  43033.35665509259   2017-10-25 10:33:34
16  43033.35665509259   2017-10-25 10:33:34
17  43033.35666666667   2017-10-25 10:33:36
18  43033.35666666667   2017-10-25 10:33:36
19  43033.35666666667   2017-10-25 10:33:36
20  43033.35666666667   2017-10-25 10:33:36
21  43033.35667824074   2017-10-25 10:33:37
```

As you see, I get four times 32" (what ist right), 4 times 33" what is also right, but then I get 8 times 34" what is wrong (check the raw values of excel).

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate your help...

Comment: Are those excel values in your first data sample text strings?  They seem to have more precision than Excel allows.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I see what you mean. I used the following function: read_excel() to import my data. What you see here is the result of my import. Why the result here is more precise than what I can get in excel is for me foggy.

Comment: I don't understand that either.  If those values are entered into Excel as numeric values, they will be rounded to ten decimal places.  Clearly something funny going on with your import process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you convert to dates, you lose precision. Change from excel date to date-time directly by converting days into seconds and use `as.POSIXct`.

```
df$Time_R <- as.POSIXct(df$time_excel * 60 * 60 * 24, origin="1899-12-30")
```

Comment: Much better. But if I run a stat tool (like rle()) over my whole dataset (~4500 entries) and plot the Histogramm, I still get ~200 "8" versus ~800 "4". Where am I loosing precision ?

Comment: @Julien I am not exactly sure about the complete data. Seems to work for me on the data that you shared.

Comment: Is there a way I could share my whole data set with you... ?